# Moving flask functions to separate file

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a flask file and I am trying to to take some of the functionality and methods and place them in a separate python file so that it is easier to work with and creates a file that is just for functionality in my flask app. I have looked up how to do but for some reason it is not working with me and I was hoping someone can help me. I have file snippets and github link below.

github: https://github.com/omar-jandali/RoadTripWebsite

original **init**.py file:

```
import modu
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask import escape, session
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Users, Groups, Records, Base

@app.route('/validate_registration', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Validate_Registration():
    usernameMinChars = 4
    usernameMaxChars = 12
    passwordMinChars = 8
    passwordMaxChars = 14

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # this is all of the fields in the form
        username = request.form['username']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        verify = request.form['verify']
        check_username = db_session.query(Users).filter_by(Username = username).\
                            first()
        check_email = db_session.query(Users).filter_by(Email = email).first()

        if username != None:
            if len(username) >= usernameMinChars:
                if len(username) <= usernameMaxChars:
                    if check_username == None:
                        valid_username = username
                    else:
                        flash('The username ' + username + ' is already in use')
                        return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
                else:
                    flash('The username is too long')
                    return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
            else:
                flash('The username is too short')
                return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
        else:
            flash('Youh ave to enter a username to register')
            return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
```

Changed server/**init**.py file (I want to chagne it so that I call a def in a different file in order to validate the username and submit the username if valid.)

Replace:

```
if username != None:
            if len(username) >= usernameMinChars:
                if len(username) <= usernameMaxChars:
                    if check_username == None:
                        valid_username = username
                    else:
                        flash('The username ' + username + ' is already in use')
                        return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
                else:
                    flash('The username is too long')
                    return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
            else:
                flash('The username is too short')
                return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
        else:
            flash('Youh ave to enter a username to register')
            return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
```

with:

```
valid_username = modu.ValidateUsername(check_username)
```

** I have added a new file called modu in the same file directory that is imported at the top of the **init**.py file

Here is the modu.py file that was created to hold all of the defs in that can be called by the **init**.py file when needed:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask import escape, session
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Users, Groups, Records, Base


    def ValidateUsername(username):
        if username != None:
            if len(username) >= usernameMinChars:
                if len(username) <= usernameMaxChars:
                    if check_username == None:
                        valid_username = username
                        return valid_username
                    else:
                        flash('The username ' + username + ' is already in use')
                        return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
                else:
                    flash('The username is too long')
                    return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
            else:
                flash('The username is too short')
                return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
        else:
            flash('Youh ave to enter a username to register')
            return redirect(url_for('Registration'))
```

Comment: So, you want to return the redirect object as the variable `valid_username`??

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: I want to pass the username and check to make sure all the validations pass and if all the validations pass, I want it to return the username so that I can save it in the database. @cricket_007 would the blocks of code do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try not nesting things when you don't have to

Second, you're trying to return two different objects, so you'll need to catch that

```
def is_valid_user(username):
    go_register = False 
    if not username:
        flash('You have to enter a username to register')
        go_register = True

    if len(username) >= usernameMinChars:
        flash('The username is too long')
        go_register = True
    if len(username) <= usernameMaxChars:
        flash('The username is too short')
       go_register = True

    if not check_username:
        flash('The username ' + username + ' is already in use')
        go_register = True

    # return two items, a redirect and the username
    if go_register:
        return redirect(url_for('Registration')), None 

    # If there was no error, you don't redirect
    return None, username
```

For example,

```
go_register, valid_username = is_valid_user(username)
if go_register:
    return go_register 
else:
    flash("valid " + valid_username)
```

Comment: After looking at the code and userstanding what you were doing, I got the idea and started building it in my project. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: So i was trying to get the code working based off your example and I am happy to say that it is working. Thank you so much for the help. I will be posting my solution for others @cricket_007

Comment: Glad to hear. You may accept my answer if it has helped